# R lists put name of first element in back-ticks

Tags: r

I recently installed the latest version of R:

```
R version 3.5.0 Patched (2018-06-06 r74855) -- "Joy in Playing"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

It has the odd glitch of placing the name of the first member of a list in back-ticks:

```
> list(a = 1, b = 2)
$`a`
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```

I assume this is a bug. Or is there a reason for this oddity? Is it going to interfere with accessing list members by name?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this as well, also happens in 3.5.1.

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Also odd that you can still access the first element without the backticks

```
x
$`a`
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

x$a
[1] 1
```